# How to get dialog input?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get input from a dialog that pops up after selection of a popup menu item. I don't quite understand how to get the user's text input so that I can set it to my TextView "ListName" (see the last method). The text that I get is this: *android.widget.EditText@41f3abf8*

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.groceryrunner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Method for activity events
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.CreateLG:
            createLGPopup(v);
            break;
        case R.id.EditButton:
            findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            createEditButtonPopup(v);
            break;
        }
    }
    // findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GetStarted);
    // text.setText(choice);

    // CreateLG Button's Popup Menu
    public void createLGPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu LGMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        LGMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.createlg_menu, LGMenu.getMenu());
        LGMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String choice = new String((String) item.getTitle());
                if (choice.equals("Create List")) {
                    createListDialog();
                }
                else if (choice.equals("Create Group")) {
                    findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        LGMenu.show();
    }

    // Create Edit Button's Popup Menu
    public void createEditButtonPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu EditMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        EditMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.editlist_menu, EditMenu.getMenu());
        EditMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String choice = new String((String) item.getTitle());
                if (choice.equals("Edit List Name")) {
                    findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                else if (choice.equals("Clear List Items")) {
                    findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                else if (choice.equals("Delete List Name")) {
                    findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        EditMenu.show();
    }

    // Create List Dialog
    public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    private void createListDialog() {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText textInput = new EditText(this);      
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create list");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Name your list: ");
        dialogBuilder.setView(textInput);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ListName);
                text.setText(textInput.toString());
                //TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ListName);
                //String input = textInput.getText().toString(); //(textInput.toString());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(), "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // add list to ListsButton
                //findViewById(R.id.ListName). -> Change ListName text to created list
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(), "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
        // Output
        AlertDialog dialogue = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialogue.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: And `findViewById(R.id.ListName).setText(input);` doesn't work ?

Comment: No, because setText isn't defined for type View. Also, I don't think I'm calling textInput right maybe-I edited the file and marked where I define it above near the beginning of the method.

Comment: You can cast it if you know it will be a TextView, as you're already doing: `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.ListName)).setText(input);`. This should work. If you're not sure whether you retrieve the input text or not, debug and check the value of `input`.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah just it to that. Thanks. My problem is I'm not grabbing the right input to begin with, as my result says this in textview ListName: android.widget.EditText@41f3abf8

Comment: yeah, if you do `textInput.toString()` that's normal. I posted an answer which should now work for you, but I also see in comments in your code that you were trying `textInput.getText().toString()` at some point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what was discussed in the comments, you should be able to get it like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ListName);
    text.setText(textInput.getText().toString());
    // ...
```

1. to retrieve a view referenced in the activity (here `ListName`), `findViewById()` from within the dialog callback works since the dialog is defined as a nested class of the activity and thus `findViewById()` is translated to `MainActivity.this.findViewById()` so it should find `ListName` fine. It also has to be cast to use methods specific to the `TextView` class.
2. if you write `textInput.toString()`, you'll be calling the `toString()` method of a `TextView` object. It looks like `TextView` doesn't override `toString()`, so this is the default `Object#toString()` method which just returns the name of the type of the object plus its hash code (that's why you see `android.widget.EditText@41f3abf8`). You need to get the `CharacterSequence` from the view first (`textInput.getText()`).

Comment: aha of course, that makes perfect sense. Just tried it out, workin like a charm. Thanks desseim!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the dialog's context when calling findViewById.  Like this dialog.findViewById(R.id.ListName), instead of just findViewById(R.id.ListName). The dialog is passed into the onClick() method as a parameter just for this reason.

Comment: My understanding, although I can't be sure since he didn't paste the whole code, is that `ListName` he's trying to set is part of the activity layout, not the dialog. So in this case, `findViewById(R.id.ListName)` being effectively `MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.ListName)`, it should be right.

Comment: Correct, ListName is a TextView on the main screen. Once I type the input for the dialog (textInput) and press Create, I want the text to display in ListName. However, I'm not grabbing it correctly since I'm getting this instead of the user input: android.widget.EditText@41f3abf8

Answer (score 0):

add this inside your onClick: `text.setText(input);`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too (I updated my original post):  text.setText(textInput.toString());

My problem is getting the actual text, since I'm not grabbing it correctly with textInput.